# Are のだぞ、のさ、のだ grammatically wrong?

Tags: particle-の, explanatory-の

I've been told の is formal, thus のです is grammatically right.
Yet, のだ is not.　Only んだ would be correct.

Therefore, 「んだぜ、んさ、んだぞ、んぜ、んぞ」 are correct and 「のだぜ、のだぞ、のさ、のぜ、のぞ」 are not.

Do you agree? Why or why not？

Comment: `Yet, のだ is not. Only んだ would be correct.` Hmm? I don't think のだ is  incorrect...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the difference between んだぜ/んだぞ and のだぜ/のだぞ, yes, the former is far more common, but the latter form is still grammatical and occasionally heard. A fictional pompous person may well talk like ～のだぜ/のだぞ with their close friends.

んぜ/んぞ/のぜ/のぞ do not exist.

> - 見たんだぜ。見たんだぞ。: OK, informal male speech
> - 見たのだぜ。見たのだぞ。: Less common. pompous and/or old-fashioned
> - 見たんぜ。見たんぞ。見たのぜ。見たのぞ。: ungrammatical

I don't know why, but のさ is more common than んさ, and のよ is more common than んよ. んさ/んよ sounds a bit dialectal to me.

> - 見たのさ。: OK, informal male speech
> - 見たのよ。: OK, informal female speech
> - 見たんさ。見たんよ。: dialectal